# C# Regex - How to ignore escape sequences with variables

Tags: c#, regex

Say I have this code:

```
foreach (string filepath in someList)
{
    someBool = Regex.IsMatch(someString, filepath);
}
```

Where `someBool`, `someList`, and `someString` are just a random boolean, list, and string, respectively (This is a simple example of what I'm trying to do).  `Filepath` is a filepath, with a bunch of backslashes (i.e. C:\\somefolder\somefile).  The problem is by running this code, I get an `ArgumentException` error, with an "unrecognized escape sequence" problem for things like "D:\\H..."  I tried using

```
someBool = Regex.IsMatch(someString, @filepath);
```

and I am still seeing the error.  Is there something else I'm forgetting?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the same error with `someBool = Regex.IsMatch(someString, @filepath);` ?

Comment: @manoj: That's not not what `@` does.  `@` allows you to use variables like `@if`.  It doesn't magically tell `Regex` how to read the string.

Comment: You are treating the filepath as a regular expression??!! It is not one, and so you are of course going to get errors. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Bony: I assume that he's concatenating them into a larger regex.

Comment: If you are just looking for the filepath within the string then you should use someBool = (someString.IndexOf(filepath) >=0)

Comment: Well, I am trying to see if a line in a text file contains the filepath in it, in a nutshell.

Comment: @SLaks -  `That's not not what @ does` - I didn't say use this and try. That is what the OP had given. `It doesn't magically tell Regex how to read the string.` - I think that is what the OP had intended, but not me :). `@ allows you to use variables like @if` - I didn't know `@` had that use. So my question was wrong / irrelevant in a way.

Comment: @manoj: Sorry; I misinterpreted.  The first half of my comment should therefore be directed at @evan.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried using `Regex.Escape`

```
Regex.IsMatch(someString, Regex.Escape(filepath));
```

Comment: May want to add `, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`